# Difference between 'which' and 'that' in restrictive (defining) relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, which-that

Excuse me if this topic has been brought up before though I couldn't find it. It seems that there are many similar topics related to both defining and non-defining clauses but there is still one question that bothers me.
I want to know about the difference between wh- pronouns (who, which, what...) vs. that in **restrictive relative clause**.

For example:
The man that I saw at the mall looked puzzled. 
The man who I saw at the mall looked puzzled. 
I omitted commas intentionally, as I'm willing to talk about defining clauses only.

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language gives quite vague description on that and I cannot think about actual examples:

"Relative clauses are so called because they are related by their form to an antecedent. They contain within their structure an anaphoric element whose interpretation is determined by the antecedent. This anaphoric element may be overt or covert. In the overt case the relative clause is marked by the presence of one of the relative words who, whom, whose, which, etc., as or within the initial constituent: clauses of this type we call wh relatives. In non-wh relatives the anaphoric element is covert, a gap; this class is then subdivided into that relatives and bare relatives depending on the presence or absence of that."
Thanks in advance!

UPD: I know that it seems that in general there is no need to dig for this information but still I need this for my research.

Comment: I don't know if there ***is*** any difference.

Comment: Well, if there weren't any why would someone invent two different words.

Comment: I would agree with @Peter: there is no real difference. Often, _that_ appears more colloquial and less formal than _who_ or _which_ (and especially much less formal than _whom_), but that is the only difference to me. Note, though, that ‘that’ and ‘what’ are not interchangeable, at least not in any context that I can think of.

Comment: Nobody **invented** two different words. Language is as it is, not as somebody thinks it should be to be tidier, more logical, or easier to learn.

Comment: @ColinFine I know, I just used 'invented' ironically, I can't tell the difference too, anyways, thanks so much for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Janus Bahs Jacquet states in the comments, the difference is essentially one of formality. The *Cambridge Grammar of English* states the following general principle:

> In a wide range of informal styles, *that* is used instead of *who/whom* or
>   *which* in defining relative clauses. (p571)

This principle is confirmed by Swan in *Practical English Usage*:

> We often use *that* instead of *who* or *which*, especially in an informal
>   style. (p478)

Swan goes on to note:

> *That* is especially common after quantifiers like *all, every(thing), something, any(thing), nothing, little, few, much, only*, and after
>   superlatives. (p478)

When the relative reference is to a person, Swan states:

> *That* is often used in identifying relative clauses instead of
>   *who/whom/which*. *That* is most common as an object or as a subject
>   instead of which. *That* can be used as a subject instead of *who*, but
>   this is quite informal. (p482)

The *Cambridge Grammar of English* notes (of defining/identifying relative clauses):

> *That* may refer to the complement of a preposition, but not when the
>   preposition is placed immediately before the relative pronoun:
>
> - The other girl that I told you about also lives in Bristol.

So, the following is not grammatical:

> The other girl about that I told you also lives in Bristol.

It must be: *... about whom ...* . Of course, this very formal usage conforms to the general principle noted above.

Comment: That was very useful, thank you very much! I wish I had more reputation to vote up for that :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might have a copy of the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*. If so, then there's probably a section in there that addresses your question.

In my copy (printed in 2008, with corrections), there's within Chapter 12 the section 3.5.4 "The choice between the *wh* and non-*wh* constructions", pages 1052-4. It contains stuff like:

- (d) *That which* and *all* who: obligatory *wh* -- which has the example "*That which we so carefully created he has wantonly destroyed*".
- (e) *Anything, all,* etc.: non-*wh* preferred -- which has the examples "*Anything (that) you say may be used in evidence against you*", "*All (that) I ask for is a little peace and quiet*".
- (f) Nominals with superlative modifiers: non-*wh* preferred -- which has the examples "*She gave me the best meal (that) I'd had for many years*", "*You should take the first appointment that is available*", "*That fish is the biggest (that) I've ever seen*".
- (g) Relativised element is ascriptive predicative complement: normally non-*wh* -- which has the examples "*He's no longer the trustworthy friend (that) he was in those days*", "*The interview turned out not to be the ordeal (that) I had thought it would be*".

There's more info in *CGEL* that might interest you.

Comment: Can't vote up for you answer as I lack reputation but thanks a lot

Comment: @wibble: You should be able to accept this post if it adequately answered your question.