# Can "that" stand after a comma?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses

[image: A scene from the game "Genshin Impact"]

Is the underlined "that" used accurately there?

I suppose it is a relative clause, based on its meaning and function but this dialogue has been bugging me for a while since all I've learned is "that" never goes after a comma, in any cases. Is it something I'm unaware of or just an error?

If it is correct, how often is it to encounter it? Is there a meaning behind it?

Comment: You suppose correctly: it is a relative clause. It's introduced by "that", which means more specifically that it's a non-defining relative clause, one that should not be set apart by punctuation like the commas in the example.

Comment: This one sure helps. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it grammatical to use the relative pronoun “that” after a comma?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325930/is-it-grammatical-to-use-the-relative-pronoun-that-after-a-comma) While tchrist gives a fine answer that does not label all commas before non-defining that-clauses incorrect, in this case 'who' sounds far more idiomatic. The justification for the unusual rule-breaking for which tchrist argues in the other thread does not apply here.

Comment: If you use a non-defining _that_ relative clause set off by punctuation you are liable to be marked down in an examination. Except in a very few special constructions, they are ungrammatical, as indeed yours is. Don't let anyone tell you otherwise.

Comment: I see. So it's best not to use it then. 

Thanks a bunch for helping me out, though.